# how to solve "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, excel, jquery-ui

I am working on putting a project and one part of project is retrieving all the data from excel cells into  an array for autosuggestion jquery like the one in the [autocomplete module link](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

So far I achieved to put data from excel into **PHP** array than convert into **JQuery** array with help **Json_encode** and by using flattenArray function all my data is in a single dimensional Array.

Autocomplete function works when my data comes out of an basic excel data which looks like:[image]

however when I put a little bit complicated data like this:
[image]

I face of with a problem **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list** when data goes exactly into my

```
 $(function(){var availableTags = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($myFlatArray); ?>');
```

*my question how can I prevent this error appearing and autocomplete works fine?*

Edit:
here is my code...

```
    <?php

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, [
    realpath(__DIR__ . '/Classes'), // assuming Classes is in the same directory as this script
    get_include_path()
]));
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';

$file= "./uploads/".$_GET["filename"];
$inputFileName = ($file);

//  Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}



//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn

$total=array();

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
{ 
    //  Read a row of data into an array

    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                    NULL,
                                    TRUE,
                                   FALSE);

//  echo "-----------------as rowData---------------";

//  var_dump($rowData); //  Insert row data array into your database of choice here

//    echo "-----------------VAR_DUMP total!---------------";

    array_push($total, $rowData);
//  var_dump($total);
    $myFlatArray = PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::flattenArray($total);    
    echo    "<br>";

    echo "----------------- KOVA as json encode---------------";
    var_dump(json_encode($myFlatArray));
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <script>
  $(function(){var availableTags = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($myFlatArray); ?>');
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: Change like this:- `$(function(){
var availableTags = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($myFlatArray); ?>');
});` and check

Comment: nope, it is like that @anantkumarsingh

Comment: @anantkumarsingh nope first of single and double quotation wont change the result... eventhough I knew that it won't help, I tried and answer is no it still creates same error